# Cordova plugin add with github address slow

Tags: cordova

Something is wrong.
I tried to add a plugin (forgot which one I did, maybe `cordova-plugin-facebook4`) like this:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" --variable FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS="true"`

That's fast. However, if I add with the git repo instead:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" --variable FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS="true"`

It becomes unbearably slow. In fact, I never did let it finish. What's the hold up?

Comment: What version of Cordova CLI are you using? What output are you getting with `-d` added to the command?

Comment: The command helps me to understand that when the plugin exists under the `node_modules`, it will not fetch from web, but from the folder if no URL is specified. That's a start to figuring out if I encounter the problem again. Thanks.